# How to change the shape of TikZ's mindmap children?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, mindmaps

Consider the original example of `tikz`'s mindmap. The standard shape of both parent and children is circle. The official document states the difference of TikZ's mindmap from standard mindmaps by using perfect circles. I have some questions for basic customization:

**Question 1**: How to change the shape of `concept`s to form ellipse or rectangular?

**Question 2**: How to make the child flexible for long text? In standard mode, if having a long text, the circle will grow up (but without shift) to cover the whole mindmap.

Comment: Please post separate questions for different questions, even if they belong to the same topic.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I thought that both questions might have a single solution, as a rectangular concept child with text height can do this. In fact, the second question is meaningless without creating a non-circle concept. However, if you suggest, I will separate the questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can modify the attributes used for concepts using `every concept` (to affect all the concepts) `root concept` (to affect only the root concept), and `level 1 concept`, `level 2 concept`, ... , `level 4 concept` (to affect concepts on a per level basis).

If you are going to change the concept shape, (to a rectangular shape, for example), then probably you will also have to change the style for the connection bar used. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{circle connection bar}=[to path={
  [every circle connection bar]
  decorate [decoration={snake}]
  { -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
},
append after command={[fill=olive,draw=olive]}
]
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
  every concept/.style={rectangle,draw=olive,fill=olive!20,inner sep=8pt}]
\node [concept,text width=4cm] {\lipsum[2]}
child[grow=30] {node[concept] {child}}
child[grow=0 ] {node[concept] {child}}
child[grow=-30] {node[concept] {child}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain your code? How would this translate to a `\tikzset{...}`?