# Using tcolorbox along with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-arrows

I want to use `tcolorbox` along with `tikz`. Need some nodes with  `tcolorbox` joined with arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0em}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\newtcolorbox{GreenBox}[1]{colback = green!5!white,
colframe = green!75!black, arc = 4mm, outer arc = 1mm, fonttitle = \huge\textbf, title = #1}


\begin{GreenBox}{\textit{ASD}}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [text width = 6cm] at (0, 0) (node1) {
   \begin{GreenBox}{\textit{AS}}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item A
   \item B
   \end{itemize}
   \end{GreenBox}
   };

\node [text width = 6cm, right of = node1]  (node2) {
   \begin{GreenBox}{\textit{ASD}}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item AS
   \item BC
   \end{itemize}
   \end{GreenBox}
   }

%\node at (0,0) (node1) [shape=rectangle,fill=green] {box1}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{GreenBox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tikz instructions always end with `;` please correct your code. For the rest, can you make a freehand drawing of what you would like to get?

Comment: That's more like a mindmap with square boxes. I never did it but https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52817/38080 could give some starting point

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433080/good-practice-mindmap-like-scheme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tcolorbox` with `enhanced` skin can be `remember(ed) as` to be referenced later on inside a `tikzpicture`. This way there's no need for a `tcolorbox` inside a `TikZ node` unless you need special positioning between boxes.

Following code shows an example with OP's code. `GreenBox` definition has been changed to accept an optional parameter and making box title mandatory.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0em}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\newtcolorbox{GreenBox}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    colback = green!5!white,
    colframe = green!75!black, 
    arc = 4mm, outer arc = 1mm, 
    fonttitle = \huge\slshape\textbf, 
    title = #2,
    #1}

\begin{GreenBox}{ASD}
   \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box1, nobeforeafter]{AS}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item A
   \item B->
   \end{itemize}
   \end{GreenBox}
   \hfill
   \begin{GreenBox}[width=5cm, remember as=box2, nobeforeafter]{ASD}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item AS
   \item BC
   \end{itemize}
   \end{GreenBox}
\end{GreenBox}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, line width=1mm, draw=red]
\draw[->] (box1)--(box2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi for very helping answer. Please see my edits and guide me accordingly. Thanks

Comment: After your edits, the question is completely different. Please make a new question and provide some initial code to work with. Don't leave all the work to us.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi for your help. As you suggested I tried and asked a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551346/4821).